# plsql: inserting Multiple rows from select and ignore duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using oracle 10g with TOAD.
I need to insert lacs of records using INSERT FROM SELECT.

```
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE(C1,C2,C3)  
    SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE C1>100;
EXCEPTION    
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  THEN NULL;    
COMMIT;    
END;
```

Here, the problem , i am facing is , if this select queries return rows which is already exists in MYTABLE, THEN all transaction will be rolledback.

Is there a way to insert all non-existent rows ,ignoring duplicate rows and continuing with insertion of non-existent rows and then committing the transaction?

Comment: just do a select distinct c1,c2,c3 ... where not exists (select 1 from mytable mt where mt.c1 = mytable.c1 and mt.c2 = mytable.c2 and mt.c3 = mytable.c3)

Comment: Hi Mike, The select query gets columns from multiple tables. The three columns are from three different tables.

Comment: You beat me to the edit.  You could probably also do a merge, but as you see, there's a number of ways to do it.  Merge into mytable m1 using mytable2 m2
on (m1.c1 = m2.c1 and m1.c2 = m2.c2 and m1.c3 = m2.c3)
when not matched then
insert values(m2.c1, m2.c2, m2.c3);

Answer (score 0):

Use the Distinct Keyword

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE(C1,C2,C3)
    SELECT distinct C1,C2,C3 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE C1>100;
EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  THEN NULL;
COMMIT;
END;

Comment: Hi Sandeep,The select query gets columns from multiple tables. The three columns are from three different tables

Comment: Hello User1583751, Even if the select query fetches records from multiple tables, the distinct keyword will remove all duplicate entries of C1,C2,C3 and will then insert the records into the MYTABLE

Comment: distinct fails when using multiple tables. Select might give me distinct recordsfrom table2 , but while inserting into table1, it wont identify disctinct record in table1. select and distinct are on x table where as insertion is in y table. :)

Comment: You can use the Merge statement as suggested by Mike, can you please paste here the exact SQL query that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle the exception, you can avoid these rows in the first place, e.g., by using the `minus` operator:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (c1, c2, c3)  
SELECT c1, c2, c3 
FROM   mytable2 
WHERE  c1 > 100;
MINUS
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM   mytable
WHERE  c1 > 100 -- not necessary, but should improve performance
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I need to know which rows i am skipping in exception part. and then continue with other records. But my issue is once the exception is raised whole transaction goes for toss.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. First of all, you can try something like this:

```
insert into mytable(c1, c2, c3)
select distinct c1, c2, c3 from mytable2 where c1 > 100
minus
select c1, c2, c3 from mytable;
```

Otherwise, you can use something like

```
insert into mytable(c1, c2, c3)
select c1, c2, c3 from mytable2 where c1 > 100
log errors into myerrtable reject limit unlimited;
```

And so on...

**More detailed about error logging. Feauture introduced since 10g release 2.**

```
SQL> create table garbage(id integer);

Table created

SQL> insert into garbage select rownum from dual connect by level <= 10;

10 rows inserted

SQL> insert into garbage values (3);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into garbage values (5);

1 row inserted

SQL> create table uniq(id integer not null primary key);

Table created

SQL> insert into uniq select * from garbage;

ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SYS_C0010568) violated

SQL> select count(*) from uniq;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log('uniq', 'uniq_err');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> insert into uniq select * from garbage
  2  log errors into uniq_err reject limit unlimited;

10 rows inserted

SQL> select * from uniq;

                                     ID
---------------------------------------
                                      1
                                      2
                                      3
                                      4
                                      5
                                      6
                                      7
                                      8
                                      9
                                     10

10 rows selected

SQL> select ora_err_mesg$, id from uniq_err;

ORA_ERR_MESG$                                                          ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------- --
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SYS_C0010568) violated              3
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SYS_C0010568) violated              5
```

Comment: I get Error for your Last line "log errors into myerrtable reject limit unlimited;"

[Error] Execution (49: 5): ORA-06550: line 13, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ERRORS" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would make this an answer, but it really depends on what your trying to achieve.

You can check to see if the data is already in table2 using:

```
INSERT INTO mytable2 (c1, c2, c3) 
SELECT DISTINCT c1,c2,c3 FROM mytable t1
WHERE c1 > 100 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(select 1 from mytable2 t2 where t2.c1 = t1.c1 and t2.c2 = t1.c2 and t2.c3 = t1.c3);
```

or you can use a merge like this:

```
MERGE INTO mytable2 m2
USING (SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM mytable) m1 
ON (m1.c1 = m2.c1 and m1.c2 = m2.c2 and m1.c3 = m2.c3) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (c1, c2, c3)  VALUES (m1.c1, m1.c2, m1.c3)
where m1.c1 > 100;
```

In both examples, you will only insert unique rows into mytable2